# Toolbar - Hamburger menu width / menu buttons width

Tags: android, xamarin, imageview, android-toolbar

[image]

Currently I am using Toolbar from Support library V7 in my Android project. I am having problems centering the ImageView inside (meaning centre is width of the screen / 2). I suspect it might be because of the programatically added menu buttons on the right.

1. Is there any way how to get their width?
2. Is it possible to get the hamburger menu width as well?

I haven't really found a reliable way how to centre the image. It always gets a offset. Even though I try to set paddingLeft on the imageView to centre it with formula "SCREEN SIZE / 2 + IMAGEVIEW.WIDTH / 2" it doesn't produce satisfying results.

Comment: Are you trying to center the imageview between the hamburger menu and btn1?  If that's the case, make the ImageView's width layout params be match_parent and toLeftOf btn1 and set its scale type to FIT_CENTER

Comment: @tim.paetz unfortunately I am trying to center it on the whole screen width. So the center for the image would be screen width / 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this (also includes the ability to have subtitles on the left side next to hamburger icon):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:minHeight="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbarTitles"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarTitle"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbarSubtitle"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbarTitle" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```